# Win 10 utility to upload an image to a hosting site with just a right click

Tags: windows, utility, image

Is there a currently working utility for Windows which would let me upload an image to an image hosting site from the desktop, with just a right click? I found a few such utilities, but most of them no longer work (sites went out of business):
[Zabkat](https://www.zabkat.com/blog/27Dec09-image-uploader.htm)
[RightLoad](http://rightload.org/index.php/download.html)
[Easy Image Uploader](https://apps.nozavi.com/apps/others/older-apps.html#easy-image-uploader)